# Android - Changing text of play button while audio is playing

Tags: android, audio, android-fragments, ringtone

I'm building an app which has a part that people can save certain recording and listen to them as he wishes (that's not all the use of the app, but for simplifying things, that's it for now).

When user choose one audio from a list, he gets a view with a "Play" button.
I want that the text of this button will change to "Playing..." while the audio is playing, and change it back to "Play" once it finishes.

Here's the relevant code snippet from RecordViewFragment:

```
ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getActivity(), Uri.parse(audioLinkPath));

audioButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            ringtone.play();
            while (ringtone.isPlaying()) {
             audioButton.setText("Playing...");
            }
            audioButton.setText(R.string.item_play);
    }
});
```

What happens in reality is that the sound is played but the text is never changes (or changes really fast).
I assume that's because play() method is async method. What else can be done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
while (ringtone.isPlaying()) {
    audioButton.setText("Playing...");
}
```

All you're doing is going round and round and round in the `while` loop.

Remove this code...

```
while (ringtone.isPlaying()) {
    audioButton.setText("Playing...");
}
audioButton.setText(R.string.item_play);
```

...and just put the following in your `onClick(...)` method...

```
ringtone.play();
audioButton.setText("Playing...");
```

Then implement a callback method to be called when play stops and use that to call...

```
audioButton.setText(R.string.item_play);
```

Comment: Please explain the last part, about implementing a callback method to be called when pay stops...

Comment: never mind, done it with media player eventually, thanks